# How spring open transaction with readonly=true if there is exsiting transaction with readonly=false

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

How spring open transaction with readonly=true if there is exsiting transaction with readonly=false

```
    public void second(){...}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void first(){
second();
}
```